# How to create a collection in a local zotero library using R?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rselenium, bibliography, google-scholar

I am developing a web-scraping code looking for references on over 15,000 species names. I would like to save those references into specific zotero collections for each species in a local zotero library.

My plan is to use RSelenium for the web-scrapping, but I wonder if there is a way to create a new collection in a local zotero library using R?

I can create the collections by hand in the local zotero software, which can later be selected in the browser by RSelenium, but as you can image creating that many collection by hand will be error prone with that many species.

Comment: Zotero has a REST API. While there is no dedicated R language client library, it is quite easy to interact with REST APIs in R. See the "Creating a Collection" section on this page: https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/web_api/v3/write_requests for instructions on how to create a new collection via the REST API. Note that this will allow you to create and interact with *online* Zotero libraries. There is a python library https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/87671/a-new-python-tool-kit-for-interacting-with-the-locally-hosted-zotero-database to interact with local Zotero DBs